# How do you add a Library Package Reference in Visual Studio 2010 with proxy?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I get a proxy authentication error when using the "Add Library Package Reference" dialog. But I can't figure out how to set My ID and Password.

The strange thing is that the extention manager works, but the library package manager doesnt.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, it should take your proxy info from your system settings.  You can access that from Internet explorer proxy config